# Not able to convert to JSONArray in java (android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

I am trying to run the following code but it is throwing an Exception.

**Code**

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject  = new JSONObject(result);    
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("current");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The main exception is due to the JSONArray part.If i remove that part than the code runs fine.

**Following is the API:**

```
{
"location": {
    "name": "Paris",
    "region": "Ile-de-France",
    "country": "France",
    "lat": 48.87,
    "lon": 2.33,
    "tz_id": "Europe/Paris",
    "localtime_epoch": 1480463619,
    "localtime": "2016-11-29 23:53"
},
"current": {
    "last_updated_epoch": 1480463580,
    "last_updated": "2016-11-29 23:53",
    "temp_c": -1,
    "temp_f": 30.2,
    "is_day": 0,
    "condition": {
        "text": "Clear",
        "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png",
        "code": 1000
    },
    "wind_mph": 0,
    "wind_kph": 0,
    "wind_degree": 0,
    "wind_dir": "N",
    "pressure_mb": 1033,
    "pressure_in": 31,
    "precip_mm": 0,
    "precip_in": 0,
    "humidity": 69,
    "cloud": 0,
    "feelslike_c": -1,
    "feelslike_f": 30.2
}
}
```

**Exception that occurs:**

> ```
>  W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value
>  {"last_updated_epoch":1480477541,"last_updated":"2016-11-30
>  03:45","temp_c":13,"temp_f":55.4,"is_day":0,"condition":{"text":"Overcast","icon":"\/\/cdn.apixu.com\/weather\/64x64\/night\/122.png","code":1009},"wind_mph":0,"wind_kph":0,"wind_degree":0,"wind_dir":"N","pressure_mb":1016,"pressure_in":30.5,"precip_mm":0,"precip_in":0,"humidity":77,"cloud":0,"feelslike_c":13,"feelslike_f":55.4}
>  at current of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to
>  JSONArray
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In your `Json`, `current` seems to be an object rather than array. So changing

`jsonObject.getJSONArray("current");`

to

`jsonObject.getJSONObject("current");`

will fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

`'current'` is not array, it is a JSON object, so parse it as a object, then you can retrieve data from it. 
You can use

[JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

for better/understandable view of your JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use Gson library to convert all those json to object class.. easy to get and set without to iterate the json again and again.

Create model class name **LocationModel**

```
public class LocationModel
{
    private Location location;
    private Current current;

    //create setter and getter

}
```

Create Model for **Current** Object

```
public class Current
{
    private String temp_f;
    private Condition condition;
    private String temp_c;
    private String wind_degree;
    private String wind_dir;
    private String wind_kph;
    private String is_day;
    private String pressure_in;
    private String humidity;
    private String precip_mm;
    private String wind_mph;
    private String pressure_mb;
    private String feelslike_f;
    private String cloud;
    private String last_updated_epoch;
    private String feelslike_c;
    private String last_updated;
    private String precip_in;

    //create setter and getter
}
```

Create **Condition** Model class

```
public class Condition
{
    private String icon;
    private String text;
    private String code;

    //create setter and getter
}
```

Create **Location** model class

```
public class Location
{
    private String region;
    private String localtime;
    private String localtime_epoch;
    private String lon;
    private String tz_id;
    private String name;
    private String lat;
    private String country;

    //create setter and getter
}
```

How to use?

```
LocationModel locationM = new Gson().fromJson(**YOURJSONSTRING**,LocationModel.class);

locationM.getLocation().getRegion(); //get Region <br>
locationM.getCurrent().getCondition().getText(); //get condition text from current<br>
locationM.getCurrent().getHumidity(); //get current humidity<br>
```